# Concat linq query result to string ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this simple class :

```
class A
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a dictionary  :

`Dictionary<string,A>  dic = new Dictionary<string,A>();`

```
dic["a"]=new A(){ Age=2, Name="aa"};
dic["b"]=new A(){ Age=3, Name="baa"};
dic["c"]=new A(){ Age=4, Name="caa"};
```

And here I see all the items in a visible way :

`Console.WriteLine (dic.Select(f=>f.Key+"  =>"+f.Value.Age+"      "+f.Value.Name));`

output :

```
a  =>2      aa  
b  =>3      baa  
c  =>4      caa
```

but I want it to be as a string !

something like this string value :

```
@"a  =>2      aa  \n
  b  =>3      baa  \n
  c  =>4      caa ";
```

**I could** do it with ToArray and string.join :

```
var t=dic.Select(f=>f.Key+"  =>"+f.Value.Age+"      "+f.Value.Name);
Console.WriteLine (String.Join("\n",t.ToArray() ));
```

But I'm sure there is a better ( shorter  , elegant) way
using this statement : (with a bit of addition)

`dic.Select(f=>f.Key+"  =>"+f.Value.Age+"      "+f.Value.Name)`

Any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Aggregate Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx)

```
string s = dic.Aggregate(String.Empty, 
                         (current, f) => 
                         String.Format("{0}\n{1} => {2} {3}", 
                                       current, 
                                       f.Key, 
                                       f.Value.Age,
                                       f.Value.Name))
              .TrimStart();
```

Or by using a StringBuilder

```
string s = dic.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), 
                         (current, f) => 
                         current.AppendLine(
                             String.Format("{0} => {1} {2}", 
                                 f.Key, 
                                 f.Value.Age,
                                 f.Value.Name))
              .ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You solution is fine, the only thing I would get rid of is the call to `ToArray`, so

```
Console.WriteLine (String.Join("\n",t ));
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine (String.Join(Environment.NewLine, t));
```

Comment: I think I was misunderstood :-( ..... let's say I dont have string.join....... Linq's select is iterating. and I want while iterating , to accumulate a values to a string.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, you said **( shorter , elegant)**, IMO, string.Join is shorter and elegant. As far as iteration is concerned, any other option would involve iteration, whether hidden (in case of select) or other.

Comment: You are right. I shouldn't said those words. I just wanted to learn the accumulation of strings via enumerations and not using external funcs such as tolist , string.join.